# Reactive forms: why 2-way biding works differently under Jasmine/Karma?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-reactive-forms

Typically, Karma displays the test results as well as the last tested component which you tested.

This component performs almost as fully alive, but I've noticed that it is not 100% match.

I've created a simple test app that has a form to enter text:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53122846-szzgrz?file=main.ts

If you uncomment "bootstrapApp" in the main.ts file, you will see that 2-way binding works: text entered to the field automatically displayed below it.

But if you uncomment "bootstrapTEsts" (you might need to reload the page to see the difference) you will that the test fails (the content inside of the span has not changed).

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Damn it, I made it work.

I guess 2 pieces were missed:

First, I was setting the form property the wrong way. Instead of this:

```
component.registrationForm.value.playerNick = testVal;
```

but what worked is this:

```
component.registrationForm.controls['playerNick'].setValue(testVal);
```

Dunno why, but this makes a difference.

Second, I missed doing

```
fixture.detectChanges();
```

after changing the form content and before checking updates.